# What is the assumption of jacobi's formula?

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let $A$ be any real number $m \times m$ matrix and any elements $a_{ij}$ of $A$ be defined as a function of $t$. That is : $$ A=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
 a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1m} \\
 a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2m} \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
 a_{m1} & a_{m2} & \cdots & a_{mm}
\end{array}\right) and \ a_{ij}=f(t)$$

Then, in jacobi's formula (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula), if $A$ is a differentiable map from the real numbers to $n × n$ matrix,
$$
{\displaystyle {\frac {\partial}{\partial t}}\det A(t)=\operatorname {tr} \left(\operatorname {adj} (A(t))\,{\frac {\partial A(t)}{\partial t}}\right)}
$$

$$
$$
What is a differentiable map here? Does it mean that $\frac {\partial A(t)}{\partial t}$ exists?

Then, if $\frac {\partial A(t)}{\partial t}$ exists, the above equality holds?

Comment: Yes. Also I wouldn't say "$a_{ij}=f(t)$," because that makes it look like all the $a_{ij}$s are  the same.

Comment: @runway44 thank you for your answer